# Possible Memory Leak in UIAutomationClient.DLL in Windows 11

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-ui-automation

I call the following API using c# over and over again using a timer. All it does is that it gets the top level windows on my desktop and does nothing else.

```
 AutomationElementCollection desktopChildren = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
```

When you run the console application on a Windows 10 machine and check the task manager the memory consumption is stable. On Windows 11 the memory consumption just keeps increasing it.

This is my full code for the console application. To reproduce it just copy paste this code in a Visual Studio Console Application and add the necessary refs using (Ctrl + .)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Automation;
class Program
    {

        private static Timer stateTimer;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            stateTimer = new Timer(Callback,  null, 0, 1000); ;
            Console.ReadLine();
            stateTimer.Dispose();
        }

        static void Callback(object state)
        {
            AutomationElementCollection desktopChildren = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);
        }
    }
```

What I expected is that the memory consumption would be stable in Windows 11 too, but that is not the case.

Any suggestions or pointers you might have is gladly welcome. Thank you.

Comment: This is what "managed" means, memory is stable only "on the long run", not freed when you're finished using some resource. The .NET garbage collector (GC) only runs when it thinks it should. You store nothing in static storage, you don't call any (broken) native API, your code is correct. If you really want to force the GC, just call GC.Collect() and you'll see memory is back.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. I only got this doubt because it seems to happen only  on windows 11. On. Windows 10 its stable.

Comment: I see it on Win11 22H2.  Leaks about 1.3KB per AutomationElement.  Not related to threading, COM proxy, garbage collection, finalization.  This needs to be fixed by Microsoft, call Microsoft Support to get ahead.

Comment: @Deen Hi, it's Manuel here. Always follow Hans's advice, he usually knows very well what he is talking about. Open the ticket at Microsoft...

Comment: @HansPassant and Manuel thanks. We are reaching out to Microsoft support via our organisation as of now. I will let you know if anything transpires. Thanks again.